# how to update ngrx/store from backend and database dynamodb?

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-dynamodb, ngrx, ngrx-store

I want to show data on frontend using ngrx/store, data is stored in Dynamodb. so how I update my ngrx/store then passed that data to frontend views

First, I create simple application angular form which store and retrieve data in the database using backend node.js

now I want to introduce ngrx/store in my application that take data from database store it and display on frontend views, every time when I insert the new record in db that update ngrx/store and ngrx/store update views

Comment: Hi, can you explain a little bit more what you are trying to achive. you wrote _how I update my ngrx/store then passed that data to frontend views_ but ngrx is a front end library. If you want to push the data from backend to frontend you need a stateful connection like WebSocket or MQTT in order to push data from backend to frontend

Comment: i edited my post please check it

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, you want to update your db and reflect the change on the client, using NgRx as a State Manager

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

you have to set up a stateful connection form client and server such as a web socket:

> check Socket.io https://socket.io/ for that

each time you recive the change from backand you dispach an action, this action will update a piece of the store, if you subscribe to change to that piece of the store, for example:

```
store.pipe(select(getMyPieceOfStore)
```

this will be reflected to your view